# How to connect to replica set when you have multiple CA certs

Tags: mongodb, fastapi, tls1.2, mongodb-replica-set

I have deployed the replica set with servers on 3 different VMs each one having it's own certificate Key file and CA file, I am looking for a connection string that allows me to pass multiple certificate files unique to each server

The service is written in FastAPI

All the examples I looked through deploy replica set on same vm and pass the one CA certificate, I have deployed the servers on different VMs just in case the VM goes down, It's very important service hence availability is very important

Comment: I think it is rather unlikely that you have multiple CA certs, because typically certificate requests are all singed by the same CA. Anyway, I think you can simply take all CA certs and copy them into a single file.